# How does angularjs set watcher for functions?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I understand that when I have `<p>{{abc}}<p>` or `{{ng-repeat="item in list"}}` angularjs will set **watcher** for `$scope.abc` and `$scope.list`, thus their value will be checked during every digest loop.

However when I am using ng-class directive with a **function, I could not figure out what expression is angular watching**

```js
angular.module("app",[]).controller("control",function($scope){
  var clicked = false;   
  // this is the variable I would watch for and returnString is the call back...
  // but how could angular possibly know??
  $scope.toggle = function(){
    clicked = !clicked;
  }
  $scope.returnString = function(){
    if(clicked){
      return 'text-success';
    }
    return 'text-danger';
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.3.6" data-semver="3.3.6" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.0" data-semver="1.5.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="control">
    <button ng-click="toggle()">click</button>
    <h1 ng-class="returnString()">hello world</h1>
    <!--ng-class="clicked?'text-success':'text-danger'" this way angular knows what to watch...but what if I give it a function???-->
  </body>

</html>
```

in the html...angular does not know what value "returnString()" relys on, how could the framework set a watcher? or does angular simply **run ng-class expression after every digest loop**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AngularJs` can use `$watch` over a function too.

For instance, instead of `$watch('abc', function() { /* code */});`

you could do this

```
$watch(function() { return $scope.$abc; }, function() { /* code */ });
```

so `ng-class` works on the same way: if you place a function, it will apply a $watch to the function in the scope context (this meaning the function needs to be defined in the current scope)

See [$watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch) documentation in AngularDocs of how it uses a function to watch:

```
scope.$watch(
  // This function returns the value being watched. It is called for each turn of the $digest loop
  function() { return food; },
  // This is the change listener, called when the value returned from the above function changes
  function(newValue, oldValue) {
    if ( newValue !== oldValue ) {
      // Only increment the counter if the value changed
      scope.foodCounter = scope.foodCounter + 1;
    }
  }
);
```

The *thing* being watched, then, is the result of the function, which is executed in every digest loop (you can set a debug breakpoint to verify it)

Comment: +1 for the debug idea, after inserting `console.log` into the above code...every digest loop trigger the function to run twice (**minimum count for angular watcher**)

Comment: actually I am experiencing a very strange behavior, after I added `$scope.count++;` into my code...the digest loop always go to 11 times (infinite loop?) and my ng-class no longer works [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/aOzYLtpywuWs94mJzOO7?p=preview)

Comment: since you're adding a {{count}} you're adding a watch over $scope.count.. and this value is changing in every digest - you-re updating it, causing to fire another digest loop. Try to use count in a local variable in the controller, and use console.log instead. See https://plnkr.co/edit/c7dFDyXGJsQBoHstgTBs?p=preview